# Is it possible to resize the drop down menu labelled "Record array fields" in the array view of Spyder?

Tags: python, arrays, spyder

[image]

I am usinga 26" monitor with 2560x1440 resolution. When I want to inspect an array with the array viewer some of the index options of the array are not shown because the dropdown menu is so narrow that not even some of the 3 letters tags can be displayed. This is extremely annoying because I have to click through every of the non displayed tags to find the one I am looking for. There is tons of space to have this menu much wider but I can not find an option to do so.

I tried the adaptive DPI scaling but the issue persists. Is there a way to resize this menu to a useable size?